# How to solve the downloaded error while using raco command?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to install the html-parsing package, and I'm getting a 400 error.

```
raco pkg install html-parsing
```

```
Resolving "html-parsing" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/8.7/catalog/
Resolving "html-parsing" via https://pkgs.racket-lang.org
Downloading http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket/html-parsing.zip
download: error from server
  URL: http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket/html-parsing.zip
  status code: 400
  context...:
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\private\network.rkt:59:3
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\file\cache.rkt:63:2: fetch-and-continue
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\contract\private\arrow-val-first.rkt:555:3
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\private\stage.rkt:495:14
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\private\stage.rkt:115:0: stage-package/info
   [repeats 1 more time]
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\private\install.rkt:142:0: install-packages
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\private\install.rkt:953:4
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\contract\private\arrow-val-first.rkt:555:3
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\file.rkt:763:8
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\file.rkt:752:0: call-with-file-lock
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\main.rkt:223:16
   body of (submod "C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\pkg\main.rkt" main)
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\raco\raco.rkt:41:0
   body of "C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\raco\raco.rkt"
   body of "C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\raco\main.rkt"
```

However, I successfully installed other packages. I tried it on my WSL but got the same result. I wonder how to solve this problem.

Comment: trying to call "curl" on the given url, I get a 301 moved permanently error (the redirect points to the **https** variant of the url), I installed racket and the same commands worked (on linux)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem with the https url. @coredump